# Need to modify code to add 10 blank lines

Tags: excel, vba

I need this code to add 10 lines instead of just 1.

I know very little about VBA but stole this code from another site and it's almost exactly what I need.  It inserts a line below "ERROR:" but I really need it to insert 10 blank lines instead.

```
Sub BlankLine()
    'Updateby20150203
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim WorkRng As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
    Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
    Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
    Set WorkRng = WorkRng.Columns(1)
    xLastRow = WorkRng.Rows.Count
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For xRowIndex = xLastRow To 1 Step -1
        Set Rng = WorkRng.Range("A" & xRowIndex)
        If Rng.Value = "ERROR:" Then
            Rng.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The actual results are the addition of 1 line but I'm expecting 10 blank lines.

Comment: `Rng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(10,0).EntireRow.Insert `

Answer (score 1):

While the solution Raul Guerrero suggest works, it has a drawback: Inserting rows/columns is rather slow, so instead of inserting one line 10 times, it is much better to do the insert all at once.

The solution from Scott Craner (in the comments) should be much faster, but I think he has a typo. I think it should be

```
rng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(10, 1).EntireRow.Insert
```

Comment: Yes, it should be 1 not 0.

Answer (score 0):

I just made a small modification to your code...
I hope this works as you spected!

Can you try this:

```
Sub BlankLine()
    'Updateby20150203
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim WorkRng As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
    Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
    Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
    Set WorkRng = WorkRng.Columns(1)
    xLastRow = WorkRng.Rows.Count
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For xRowIndex = xLastRow To 1 Step -1
        Set Rng = WorkRng.Range("A" & xRowIndex)
        If Rng.Value = "ERROR:" Then
            For i = 1 To 10
                Rng.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
            Next
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```